# Public transactions in quorum stuck in pending in transaction pool

Tags: ethereum, raft, quorum

I followed Quorum's docs and have created a 2 node network using the raft-consensus. In the genesis block i had pre-allocated funds to one of the accounts. Now I am trying to do a public transaction of some ethers to the other node.
However the transaction is getting stuck in the transaction pool and the balances of both nodes remain unchanged.
I have used the same genesis.json file that was provided in the documentation. Is there something I am missing?

Once the two nodes were brought up, I tried running - 
eth.sendTransaction({from:current-node-address, to: second-node's-address, value:0x200,gas:21000})

On checking the transactionReceipt with the transaction hash that was generated, it displays null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your network is not minting blocks, so you may have some Raft misconfiguration.

Check the log files for any error messages.
You can also check that both nodes are in the network and that one of them is minting (is the leader) by using the command `raft` in the geth console.

Comment: Okay so I think what you have suggested is correct. My raft command says-
{
  cluster: [null],
  leader: undefined,
  role: "verifier",
  addPeer: function(),
  getCluster: function(callback),
  getLeader: function(callback),
  getRole: function(callback),
  removePeer: function()
}

How can I fix this?I have followed the documentation exactly as mentioned in docs.

Comment: Check the docs [here](https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Getting-Started-From-Scratch/#quorum-with-raft-consensus) to make sure you added the second node correctly and have set up your configs correctly.

If it's still not working, then the easiest way to do it is to re-initialise both nodes, make sure both nodes are in the static-nodes.json file on *both* nodes. Then restart the network. This method doesn't require you to perform `addPeer`.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you initially created a network with more nodes and then removed some, the correct steps to do this must be followed. Otherwise you can end up with a non-consensus network which won't mint blocks.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was able to setup a raft-cluster by reinitializing the nodes.